# JQuery bing slider implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a slider similar to what is on bing.com. All the slider examples I see on the net have the content(text, textbox etc.) & the background image of the slider changing when the next and previous button are clicked.

I am looking for something where only the background image is changing and NOT the content on top of it. Please let me know if you have come across anyone using it using JQuery or other JS library. Thank you.

Comment: The content meaning the search box, but not meaning the mouseover / tooltips that alternate with the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is CSS absolute positioning. Place your content, that you want to stay the same, above your slider. Put the images inside the slider.

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8WjYe/

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

Comment: Hello, I am planning to use one of the responsive templates for this project. Example slider is http://oakland-responsive.cmsmasters.net/index.html The reason for choosing responsive slider is it should work OK on web, ipad, mobile. If we use responsive page, the absolute position will not work. Please let me know is there any other way we can achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: There is no reason why absolute positioning and responsive support would exclude each other. Look at this page http://www.domusacta.de/ It uses absolute positioning for the image captions and supports handheld resolutions.